# Openining apps then firefox with multiple windows with specific URLs with a bash script

Tags: bash

### Objective

In the morning when I get in to the office, I want to be able to just run a script which launches all of my apps and browser with a specific set of URLs. But the URLs all need to be in different tabs.

### Background

I currently have this script called `startup.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

open /Applications/Firefox.app &
open /Applications/Transmit.app &
open /Applications/Sublime Text 2 &
open /Applications/Messages.app &
open /Applications/GitHub.app &
open "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Outlook.app"

exit 0
```

But to open up various URLs i found other answers on SO. But none that address opening them in sets in different windows. So I tried this but it failed

```
#!/bin/sh

open /Applications/Firefox.app &
open /Applications/Transmit.app &
open /Applications/Sublime Text 2 &
open /Applications/Messages.app &
open /Applications/GitHub.app &
open "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Outlook.app"

firefox -new-tab 'http://podio.com'

#Different window
firefox -new-tab 'http://timedesk.org'
firefox -new-tab 'http://twiter.com'
firefox -new-tab 'http://rdio.com'
firefox -new-tab 'http://gmail.com'

#Different window
firefox -new-tab 'http://github.com'
firefox -new-tab 'http://stackoverflow.com'

exit 0
```

But that did not work and I got this set of errors

```
The files /Applications/Sublime, /Users/juan.gallardo/Text, and /Users/juan.gallardo/2 do not exist.
startup.sh: line 10: firefox: command not found
startup.sh: line 13: firefox: command not found
startup.sh: line 14: firefox: command not found
startup.sh: line 15: firefox: command not found
startup.sh: line 16: firefox: command not found
startup.sh: line 19: firefox: command not found
startup.sh: line 20: firefox: command not found
```

So in addition to not starting those URLs, sublime is also not starting.

Comment: If you're not satisfied with answers you get here, ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sublime's not working because the filename is not in quotes.

If firefox is your default browser, then `open http://podio.com` should work.

Comment: Cool, solved that part of the problem  with `open "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app"` . Thanks